# Erro :"GetLifeCycleBase" not found. You need to call "Get.put(GetLifeCycleBase())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>GetLifeCycleBase())"

Tags: flutter, dart, firestore

Estou usando o getX para gerência de estado e estou tendo um erro que diz o seguinte:

> "GetLifeCycleBase" not found. You need to call "Get.put(GetLifeCycleBase())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>GetLifeCycleBase())"

Eis a view:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_stock/controllers/product_controller.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
class HistoryScreen extends GetWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: GetX<ProductController>(
      init: Get.put(ProductController()),
      builder: (ProductController productController) {
        if (productController != null) {
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: productController.produtos.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return Text(productController.produtos[index].nome);
              },
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
      },
    )));
  }
}
```

O controller:

```
import 'package:flutter_application_stock/models/produto_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_stock/services/database.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
class ProductController extends GetxController {
  Rx<List<ProductModel>> productList = Rx<List<ProductModel>>();
  List<ProductModel> get produtos => productList.value;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    productList.bindStream(Database().productStream());
  }
}
```

A database:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_stock/models/produto_model.dart';
class Database {
  Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  Stream<List<ProductModel>> productStream() {
    return _firestore
        .collection("products")
        .snapshots()
        .map((QuerySnapshot query) {
      List<ProductModel> retVal = List();
      query.documents.forEach((element) {
        retVal.add(ProductModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(element));
      });
      return retVal;
    });
  }
}
```

o model:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
class ProductModel {
  String id;
  String nome;
  String embalagem;
  String categoria;
  ProductModel({this.id, this.nome, this.embalagem, this.categoria});
  ProductModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    id = snapshot.documentID;
    nome = snapshot.data["nome"];
    embalagem = snapshot.data["embalagem"];
    categoria = snapshot.data["categoria"];
  }
}
```

Agradeceria qualquer ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que até seja má pratica registrar singleton dentro de `init:` do `GetX()`, o init já precisa de uma instância pronta para usá-la e não que ainda precise registrá-la.

```
init: Get.put(ProductController())
```

Normalmente você registra antes em algum lugar, por exemplo no main, ou usando bindings, onde registra suas dependencias automaticamente.

Experienta chamar o códido abaixo no main.dart para ver se da o mesmo erro.

```
Get.put(ProductController())
// ou
Get.lazyPut(() => ProductController());
```